# Ajax delete div doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following script

```
 $('a[name=deleteButton]').on('click', function () {
        arr=[];
        var arr = $("input[name='post[]']:checked").map(function() { 
                return this.value; 
              }).get();
              var content = $(this).parents('tr').find('.key').html();
              $(this).parents('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();}); //THIS IS THE ONE WHICH FADES THE ROW 

              makeAjaxCall(content);

             return false;

    });

    function makeAjaxCall(content){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://localhost/partner/app/deleteRowUsingApiKey/delete",
            cache: false,               
            data: {id : content},
            success: function(data){                        
                   // alert(data);

            //BUT IM NOT ABLE TO USE IT HERE,IN THE SUCCESS

            },
            error: function(td){                        

            }
     });

    }
```

I have a line `$(this).parents('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});`
which removes the div.But Im not able to use it inside the success of the ajax.Can anyone tell me why.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

pass the `$(this)` reference while calling the function,

```
makeAjaxCall(content,$(this));
```

receive it like,

```
function makeAjaxCall(content, _this) {
```

and in the success call back,

```
  success: function(data){ 
      _this.parents('tr').fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});                 
  }
```